# Length of the binary representation of a primorial

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $p_n\# = \prod_{k=1}^n p_k$ be the $n$-th primorial.

> Q1. Given $n$ (in binary) is there an efficient way (polynomial time) to calculate the exact number of digits of the binary representation of $p_n\#$; in other words calculate $m$ such that $2^m \leq p_n\# < 2^{m+1}$

**Edit**: The problem seems harder than I thought, so also the following could help:

> Q2. Does the problem become easier if we "drop" a fixed number of low primes, i.e. we want to calculate the exact number of digits of the binary representation of $p_n\#^* = \prod_{k=a}^n p_k$ for some fixed $a$ ? And if we further relax it to $a = \log n$ ?

Comment: $n^n$ is a good upper bound to the nth primorial.  Looking at estimates involving Chebyshev functions should easily get you to within a few bits.  You might also consider estimations using ratios of factorials or perhaps binomial coefficients.  Gerhard "Ask Me About Estimating Primes" Paseman, 2015.01.22

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: I was wondering if there is an efficient way to calculate the *exact* number of bits. (I'm not an expert of number theory, but the result could help me to refine a problem in computational complexity)

Comment: Of course.  I don't know the error in $\log (n^n/p\#_n)$, but I imagine it is small enough to be of use.  You might consider the complexity of computing (the binary length of) $n^n$ to get a rough idea of what to hope for an answer to your question.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2015.01.22

Comment: It seems $n^n$ is a good upper bound only for some small $n \gt 3$.  I will look at this more.  Gerhard "Still A Few Bits Off" Paseman, 2015.01.22

Comment: $p_n=n\log n+n\log\log n+O(n)$, hence $\log(p_n\#)=\theta(p_n)=n\log n+n\log\log n+O(n)$, so the $\log(n^n)$ estimate is only good to a handful of leading bits.

Comment: Why should Q2 be easier that Q1?

Answer (score 1):

I believe no polynomial in $\log_2 n$ algorithm is known, since this is related to open problems.

Call your function $f(n)$. It is closely related to [Chebyshev theta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function)

$$    \vartheta(x)=\sum_{p\le x} \log p $$

If you know $f(n)$ by base change of the logarithm you get very
good approximation to $\vartheta(p_n)$ the error being small constant.

As far as I know, no such good approximations are known.

It is an open problem when $\vartheta(x) > li(x)$ see
[here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/191047/when-is-varthetaxx-skewes-number-analog).

Efficient computation of theta can be used for verification of
Riemann hypothesis because of conditional bounds.

If it is of partial interest, there are bounds for theta (and $f(n)$)
both unconditional and better conditional.